# How to check a collection isEmpty in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I am checking a email from DB. The email does not exist. But, how can I check the collection has no matching row? I am using `isEmpty()` method but it's not working. Don't know why this is happening. Following is my code:

```
$conflictUser = User::where('email',$newEmail)->get();

if($conflictUser->isEmpty()) {
    abort(409, 'Email Adresse existiert bereits.');
}
```

I achieved the goal using `**count() == 0**`. But why `isEmpty()` is not working that is my question.

Comment: @sta that returns false on an empty collection object. I think your initial comment was correct though. `!$conflictUser->isEmpty()` and that it's a logic error. Else the posted code might not match the issue.

Comment: if the collection "is empty" then it didn't find a record

Answer (score 2):

Firstwhere:

```
$conflictUser = User::firstWhere(['email' =>  $newEmail ]) !== null;
```

First:

```
$conflictUser = $items->first(function($item) use($newEmail) { 
      return  $item->email === $newEmail;
}) !== null;`
```

Filter:

```
$conflictUser = $items->filter(function($item) use($conflictUser) { 
    return $item->emp_id === $needle && $item->dst_id === $needle;
})->count() > 0;
```

I had this problem and it helped to solve it, I hope it helps